# Safari Inspect Element: Is there a way to collapse the cascade to a combined result?

Tags: safari, web-inspector, css

I'm using the Inspect Element feature in Safari.

Long ago, I used Firefox because it was the first that I knew off to come out with Firebug.  One of the features it had is when it displayed the style of an element, it had the sequence of styles and the place that each stanza had came from as Safari does now but it also had a toggle that would collapse the list of styles into the resulting set of parameters.

Is there a way to do that in Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Computed tab has a Properties section that shows the resultant properties

[image]